# TransitioningDelegate doesn't work for UIPresentationController when separated to a custom class inherited from NSObject

Tags: swift, delegates, uipresentationcontroller

I use custom UIPresentationController to perform sequel with my own animation. In `prepareForSegue:`

```
myDestinationController.transitioningDelegate = DBViewControllerTransitioningDelegate()
myDestinationController.modalPresentationStyle = .Custom
```

This is mine `DBViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`:

```
class DBViewControllerTransitioningDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return DBOverlayPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }

    func animationControllerForPresentedController(presented: UIViewController, presentingController presenting: UIViewController, sourceController source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return DBTransitioningAnimator()
    }
}
```

It is not working, because the methods are not called. But when I set:

```
myDestinationController.transitioningDelegate = self
```

and within my `self` controller add 2 methods from my `DBViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` everything is fine. These two methods are called. Why? What is the difference?

Comment: you might need to instantiate your animator beforehand. Like in an `init()` of your delegate class

Answer (score 3):

> Declaration for `transitioningDelegate` in `UIViewController`:
>
> `weak var transitioningDelegate: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate?`

As you can see `transitioningDelegate` holding a `weak` reference. The custom TransitioningDelegate instance got released right after you created it since no one have the ownership here. When you adopt the delegate in the "controller" and assign it to `transitioningDelegate` 'someone' is keeping this delegate instance for you.